# Solid reasons for switching off mobile devices on air planes

Tags: radio, mobile

Recently a flight attendant forced me to shut down my tablet PC for the period of landing the air plane, despite wireless and bluetooth being in air plane mode already.

Questions:

- Are there reported cases of mobile devices influencing airborne safety (with or without radio on)?
- Can an operating devices in "airplane mode" even hypothetically influence an aircraft?

Comment: If an electronic device like a phone were dangerous, they'd never let it on the plane in the first place instead of depending on compliance in the air

Comment: @ScottSeidman That's what one would hope. But then I thought of cities that had banned the use of mobile phones on public transport because of annoyingly loud phone talkers ... and had to back down to the mob.

Comment: I can't find a good reference to post an answer, but I believe an FAA study found no realistic problems with intereference and now it was considered more a matter of physical safety (flying laptops etc) and people ignoring safety messages while otherwise distracted.

Comment: @PeterJ guess what, there's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft) on the issue. But it's also vague, nothing really solid there.

Comment: It's bass ackwards.  In the 21st century, if portable electronic devices can interfere with avionics in dangerous ways, the avionics need to be hardened, or the devices cannot go in or near planes.

Comment: Please look [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1118/956). This is more of a skeptics question.

Answer (score 3):

- Are there reported cases of mobile devices influencing airborne safety (with or without radio on)?

Hearsay is hearsay. The plural of anecdotes is not data. There are plenty of anecdotes, but none that have been reproduced under controlled conditions.

- Can an operating devices in "airplane mode" even hypothetically influence an aircraft?

This depends on how you define "aircraft". Can, under laboratory conditions, radio-emitting devices (e.g. devices **not** in "airplane mode") cause momentary issues with the aircraft avionics that use RF (such as GPS and radio-location beacons)? Yes.

Can such interference affect anything other then the displayed information in the cockpit? No.
In other words, the interference won't crash the plane, cause the control surfaces to deflect, or anything. It just makes the position/heading/whatever readout display incorrect information.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft) on this is a good source. There are already a number of airlines that are allowing people to make cellular calls during flights, let alone use devices in "airplane mode".

Comment: In "fly by wire" systems, you can't _assume_ that interference won't affect the control systems.

Comment: Bad readouts or other bad information to control systems can and do crash planes. This is because the control systems, whether human or automated, do the wrong things in response to the bad data.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I certainly agree there may be a case to be made for enforcing "airplane mode", though the extent to which aircraft systems are hardened against RFI certainly makes it seem a bit silly. If an airplane can handle being swept with the kilowatts of the airfield radar system, or some asshole with a 20W CB in his car next to the runway, I would think the paltry watt or two that portable electronics produce will not likely have an effect.

Comment: Remember that planes can carry 300 or more people so the combined effect of that many transmitters can be considerable. We expect airlines to err on the side of safety so turning off electronic devices for a few hours is not a big deal.